# What are x,y and curve parameters of the Apple signing key used to sign push notification tokens?

Tags: php, push-notification, jwt, apple-push-notifications

As I understood, I have 2 ways of sending push notification to Apple APN : certificate-based, and token-based. I chose token-based

Apple guide says we need to create a token and refresh it every hour at least. So, i created a cron job that refreshes this token every hour and put it in a file on my server. Another cron job reads this token to send new pending push notification every second.

The problem comes in the refresh_token job, that I launch every hour. I use this librairy to create the JWT : https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/v/v2.x/components/signed-tokens-jws/jws-creation

Here is my code ( i just followed the guide I've just given as link) :

```
$algorithmManager = AlgorithmManager::create([
    new ES256()
]);


// Our key.
$jwk = new JWK([
    'kty' => 'EC', // *** PROBLEM HERE ***
    'k' => $keyFile
]);

// The JSON Converter.
$jsonConverter = new StandardConverter();

// We instantiate our JWS Builder.
$jwsBuilder = new JWSBuilder(
    $jsonConverter,
    $algorithmManager
);

// The payload we want to sign. The payload MUST be a string hence we use our JSON Converter.
$payload = $jsonConverter->encode([
    'iat' => time(),
    'nbf' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + 3600,

    'iss' => APPLE_TEAM_ID
]);

$jws = $jwsBuilder
    ->create()                                
    ->withPayload($payload)                 
    ->addSignature($jwk, /* with header: */['kid' => APPLE_KEY_NAME, 'alg' => 'ES256']) 
    ->build();
```

This code throws an exception at ->build(); function, at the end. It says that x, y and crv parameters are not specified in the key. These parameters seem to be related to the algorithm (ES256), because when I choose the alg provided in the JWT guide, they dont ask me for these parameters.

Though, Apple didn't provide any of these informations about the key they gave me on their website. Here is their guide : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you load the key is not correct. The key in the guide corresponds to an Octet key, not an EC one. A JWK EC key should look like [the example showed in the RFC7517 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-3) (with `crv`, `x` and `y` parameters).

You have to convert the key file you received from Apple services into a JWK EC key.
As you already have PHP on your platform, I recommend the use of the [CLI tool](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/v/v2.x/console/phar-application):

```sh
curl -OL https://github.com/web-token/jwt-app/raw/gh-pages/jose.phar
curl -OL https://github.com/web-token/jwt-app/raw/gh-pages/jose.phar.pubkey
chmod +x jose.phar

# Replace `/path/to/you/private/key/file.p8` with the actual path to your private key
./jose.phar key:load:key /path/to/you/private/key/file.p8

rm ./jose.phar
rm ./jose.phar.pubkey
```

You should get something like `{"kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","d":"…","x":"…","y":"…"}`.

The JWK can be loaded using the following line of code:

```php
$jwk = JWK::createFromJson('{"kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","d":"…","x":"…","y":"…"}');
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try this out right now. I had no idea about what wad all these JWx before, Apple guide didn’t helped me a lot...

Comment: I got exception : Uncaught Error: Class 'Jose\Component\Core\Util\Ecc\NistCurve' not found in /path/to/project/vendor/web-token/jwt-core/Util/ECKey.php:112
As it's in composer read only files i can't add a "use" statement myself to the file

Comment: The `NistCurve` class is in the package `web-token/jwt-util-ecc`. It should be installed. I will fix that ASAP. At the moment you can require it in your composer.json file

Comment: yes I just forgot to require jwt-util-ecc, thank you very much!